# <prismic-link> component not generating url's for vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, prismic.io

I am following along with [Lucie Habere](https://frontend.horse/episode/lets-build-a-site-with-vue-3-vite-and-prismic) creating a recipe site w/Vue Router & Prismic. The problem I am having is that ***prismic-link*** component on my *index.vue* page is not generating the anchor tags *href* field for vue router.

In looking in dev tools I see that in my response the results objects *url* field is blank where as on the sample site page it returns the relative path to the page:

`(i.e. url "/recipes/gluten-free-oat-dumplings").`

So, obviously the anchor tags that prismic-link generate have ***href=""*** attributes values. And therein I assume lies the problem.

Also I notice my initial query to Prismic does not include query parameters:

`(https://mybestrecipes.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2/documents/search?ref=YWhMghIAAElp5kmP&q=[[at(document.type, "recipe")]]&pageSize=100)`

whereas Lucie's example does

`(https://the-last-straw.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2/documents/search?ref=YRv4vBIAAB8AWKJm&q=[[at(document.type, "recipes")]]&routes=[{"type":"home","path":"/"},{"type":"recipes","path":"/recipes/:uid"}]&pageSize=100).`

I have also added added "runtimeCompiler :true into vue.config.js file. All to no avail. I dont know if the problem lies with my content modeling because you don't get to see the Prismic schema from the video.
Here is my prismic.js:

```
import { createPrismic } from "@prismicio/vue";

const prismic = createPrismic({
  endpoint: "mybestrecipes",
  clientConfig: {
    defaultParams: {
      routes: [
        { type: "home", path: "/" },
        { type: "recipe", path: "/recipe/:uid" },
      ],
    },
  },
});

export default prismic;
```

Here are some snapshots from devtools:

[image: url="null]

[image: tags]

[image: Headers]

Coincidentally I cloned her repo and the same problem occurred. And yet the demo site works ok.

Any help in getting this straightened out is appreciated.

Comment: Actually the demo from the example exhibits the same trouble. If you goto https://github.com/lihbr/prismic-demo-the-last-straw and clone it and run it you get the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucie here~

Indeed on the stream with Alex we used the alpha version of the kit. We have since released some breaking changes to the underlying client kit (because we're in alpha): the `routes` parameter is no longer nested under `defaultParams`, you should be fine going with something like this now:

```js
import { createPrismic } from "@prismicio/vue";

const prismic = createPrismic({
  endpoint: "mybestrecipes",
  clientConfig: {
    routes: [
      { type: "home", path: "/" },
      { type: "recipe", path: "/recipe/:uid" },
    ],
  },
});

export default prismic;
```

The live demo is still working because still using an old version of the kit :relaxed: I'll update it later this week!

Let us know if anything!